# mysql-workbench fails to connect with an error: Service org.freedesktop.secrets not provided

Tags: ubuntu, kde, mysql-workbench

Running on kubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Installed mysql-workbench from mysql.com website (not repository)

After re-install, when I try to open one of the saved sites in the Connection manager, I get the following error:

> org.freedesktop.secrets was not provided by any .service files

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution is simple:

```
sudo apt install gnome-keyring
```

It appears that mysql-workbench depends on this service, but does not specify this dependency explicitly in the .deb file. The previous installation worked on a multi-desktop system with both Gnome and KDE installed.

Comment: Here is a GitHub thread about this issue: https://github.com/Foundry376/Mailspring/issues/681